# cURL using multiple proxies in a chain

Tags: php, curl, proxy, libcurl, curl-multi

Is it possible to chain multiple proxies in a single request using cURL?

For example:
start cURL -> proxy1 -> proxy2 -> destination address

Can this be achieved using cURL?

Comment: What if proxy1 would proxy via proxy2? Then your chain would be interrupted. Which brings me to the short answer: No.

Comment: I realize they are not using cURL specifically, but programs such as SocksChain & Proxychains claim to support chaining of proxies.  Which makes me wonder how it is accomplished in general.

Comment: For general use, this program has sourcecode to read: http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/, I can't explain it from top of my head.

Comment: Sounds a lot like how [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) works which can be used using cURL even though I havent succeeded yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proxy is by definition a middle man. Software running and doing work between the client and the server. The client asks the proxy which then it turn asks the server.

"Chained" proxies would then imply that a first proxy would ask a second proxy, but as the client asks the proxy to do its request it cannot be the job of the client to ask the second proxy, but it must be the first proxy's task.

Alas: sure, if you have a proxy A that you setup to talk to another proxy B, and you tell curl to use proxy A then certainly the chained proxies will be used. I don't even see what curl could do to NOT work with it...