# how to use multiple proxies in curl?

Tags: php, curl, proxytunnel

this question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022672/curl-using-multiple-proxies-in-a-chain) but there is no speciaifc answer.

The PHP function below fetches a page using a given proxy. Can i use curl to fetch a page using two proxies?
eg: i can fetch the page http://example.com using proxy x.x.x.x:x
what i'd like to do is, fetch page http://example.com using proxy x.x.x.x:x but the the x.x.x.x:x should be connected thorough y.y.y.y:y (my server->proxy1->proxy2->destination )

```
    function fetchPage($proxy, $url, $timeout) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [cURL using multiple proxies in a chain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022672/curl-using-multiple-proxies-in-a-chain) - HTTP is point to point, not point via point to point.

Comment: @Nok Imchen, the answer is NO, like hakre said, http is point to point, if you still insist on doing so, you can use TOR wich is a kind of chained proxy, here's a great tutorial for getting it working: www.ferrassi.com/2011/08/php-tor-–-anonymity-with-php-curl/

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV, i'm new to TOR. Do i have to install TOR in my server to use it?

Comment: if you want a chained proxy yes, otherwise be aware of the risks of using the tor network, this may require a lot of research ...